# TypeORM for MongoDB vs mongoosejs

Tags: mongodb, typescript, express, mongoose, typeorm

Which one is best for typescript environment and what are the PROS and CONS associated with each library for mongoDB usage?

I found mongoose is not much compatible/need some work to use in typescript environment.

There is another library [typegoose](https://github.com/szokodiakos/typegoose) which provides typescript implementation on top of mongoosejs but looks like it need to support some more features of mongoosejs.

Also I found TypeOrm is primarily targeting Sql database more.

Please share your experience regarding typeorm for MongoDB vs mongoosejs.

Comment: Looking at the typorm documentation on mongodb, it says : TypeORM ** has basic MongoDB** support ([link](https://typeorm.io/#/mongodb)). I am under the assumptions there are limitations when it comes to more complex requirements. If given the option between typegoose and typeorm I would go with tyegoose.

Comment: I have the same question. I am searching over google. Spend a couple of hours but don't find what I looking for. I am using NestJs as Framework, MongoDB for the database. Now I am confused between Mongoose and TypeORM. Which to choose?